# How to I go to the "login" ViewController if FirebaseAuth is null?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am really new to Swift and have a really simple setup. There is a login screen and if the user logs in with correct credentials they go to the first VC in a tab bar.

The transition from login to the tab bar view controllers work fine but when I load the app I am not taken to the login screen if currentUser is nil.

Here is my check in the first VC in the tab bar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
      goToLogin()
    }
}
```

And this is the function in the same VC to go to login

```
func goToLogin() {
    let loginViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.loginViewController) as? LoginViewController

    view.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

The storyboard ID for my login VC is "loginViewController" and the Tab bar controller is my initial view controller

**Update**
My auth check in App Delegate looks like this:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        // considering the StoryboardID is same as View Controllers name.
        self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName: "Main", vcName: Constants.Storyboard.loginViewController)
       } else {
        self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName: "Main", vcName: Constants.Storyboard.homeTabBarController)
       }
```

But I am getting this error from the "homeTabBarController":

> Type 'Constants.Storyboard' has no member 'homeTabBarController'

homeTabBarController is the StoryboardId for my tab bar controller in the Main storyboard. So why is it not being recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this check in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in  `AppDelegate` not in `ViewController`. You can use the below function to change your root view controller.

In **AppDelegate.swift**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        // considering the StoryboardID is same as View Controllers name. 
        self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName: "Main", vcName: Constants.Storyboard.loginViewController)
       } else { 
        self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName: "Main", vcName: Constants.Storyboard.yourTabBarController)
       }
    return true
}


func makeRootVC(storyBoardName : String, vcName : String) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav
        let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
        let duration: TimeInterval = 0.6
        UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it would work but I posted an update where I cannot obtain the tab bar controller that I am using for navigation in the "Home" section of the app where the user lands after logging in.

Comment: `self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName: "Main", vcName: "homeTabBarController")`

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone but I have a completely black screen. If I manually set the initial VC or tab bar controller in SB then it works. But then as soon as I blank out the checkbox and programatically try to set it as you suggested it turns black.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the code in the "application" function in AppDelegate but somewhere else. And I am not able to figure out where.

Comment: set your initial view controller to login view controller in storyboard. and keep the code in AppDelegate also .

Comment: I needed to ask a few more things although your suggestions have helped a lot. In your makeRootVC function why do you specify a navigation controller in this line: let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)? I don't quite get this part.

Comment: And one additional thing pertaining to that function. I am getting this error 
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" associated with this line: 
UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have further queries. navigation controller has been added so that you can use push and pop functionality to navigate to screens. Also you can remove the last 3 lines in makeRootVC function, it will still work.